# change text color of un-clickable column css

Tags: css

I am trying to change some of the text anyone know the CSS class to change these? 
Thanks,

[image: list rich text column label and controls]

Answer (score 0):

For the text at the top the css rule is

```
td.ms-list-addnew.ms-textXLarge.ms-list-addnew-aligntop.ms-soften {
color: red;}
```

It inherits the color defined by the class *ms-soften*

For the columns you can use this rule

```
tr.ms-viewheadertr.ms-vhltr span {color: red;}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Thanks, 
columns worked great. but this did not work: td.ms-list-addnew.ms-textXLarge.ms-list-addnew-aligntop.ms-soften {
color: red;} 
Any suggestions?

Comment: I got the css class from SharePoint online, it might be different on other version of SharePoint. To know exactly what are the classes you can use the developer tools that are included in the browsers. Check this article, it will save you a lot of time. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/